# "Open in Tor" on the right side of Brave's URL bar

Tags: url, brave

How *Open in Tor* can shown on the right side of browser (Brave by default) address bar as seen on [brave.com](https://brave.com/) and other pages?

[image]

Even I wasn't able to find the proper name of those icons to go deeper. Any kindof useful information can come.

The closest what I found: [How to use the Tor network on Brave privacy-centric web browser for PC](https://www.how2shout.com/how-to/use-tor-network-brave-browser.html)

Comment: `navigation_handle()` is the term for the icons on the *right side of browser address bar*.

Answer (score 1):

With the help from outside of `stackexchange.com` I got the answer:

Using  `curl -sI https://radar.squat.net/en | grep -i onion` reveals the ***Onion-Location*** keyword which lead to **the answer**:

The [*Brave.com now has its own Tor Onion Service*](https://brave.com/new-onion-service/#content-area) announcement refers to the [*Tor Project | Onion-Location*](https://community.torproject.org/onion-services/advanced/onion-location/) page revealing:

> *You can either configure a web server to show an Onion-Location Header or add an HTML `<meta>` attribute in the website.*

---

The relevant code can be found on *GitHub*:

- [brave-core/onion_location_navigation_throttle.cc at 55e8de4e8010c82ab52fa501a60a515aaee5fa0c · brave/brave-core](https://github.com/brave/brave-core/blob/55e8de4e8010c82ab52fa501a60a515aaee5fa0c/components/tor/onion_location_navigation_throttle.cc#L73-L100)